# Increase mysql memory

Tags: mysql

i am trying to import sql file of 80MB size , but i get an error that my sql server has gone away , how can i increase the memory so that it can handle queries of more than 1 mb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in your my.cnf

```
max_allowed_packet=8M
```

Documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Answer (score 0):

Specify bigger `max_allowed_packet` in the `my.ini`, or add `--max_allowed_packet=xxM` to the run command.